# Add an array's values to a row in a numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, sum

I want to add the values in a numpy array to the values in a specific row of a numpy matrix.

Given:

```
A = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]

b = [1, 1]
```

I want to add b to the values in the first row in A. The expected output is:

```
[[1, 1], [0, 0]]
```

I tried using the "+" operator, but got an error:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.zeros(shape=(2,2))
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
>>> b = numpy.ones(shape=(1,2))
>>> b
array([[ 1.,  1.]])

>>> a[0, :] += b

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (2,) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1,2)
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between `b = [1, 1]` and `b = [[1, 1]]`. `a[0, :] += b` failed for you because broadcasting is not possible in this case.

If `b` can contain variable number of rows then we can take a slice of `a` using `b`'s length and add `b` to it.

```
>>> a = numpy.zeros(shape=(2,2))
>>> b = numpy.ones(shape=(1,2))
>>> a[:len(b)] += b
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
```

Or if `b` contains only one row then:

```
>>> a = numpy.zeros(shape=(2,2))
>>> a[0] += b[0]
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.zeros((2 , 2))
b = np.ones((1 ,2))
np.concatenate([b , np.array([a[0]])])
```